# Can I use actionListeners on JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, actionlistener

I am trying to add and actionListener to a JPanel it's self but keep getting the error"cannot find symbol". I was just wondering if it is possible to do this as I want to be able to click on the panel and make the colour change. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what i have so far.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel.*;
import java.awt.Color.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class SimpleFrame here.
 *
 * @author OFJ2
 * @version 
 */
public class Game extends JFrame 
            implements ActionListener
{
private final int ROWS = 5;
private final int COLUMS = 2;
private final int GAP = 2;
private final int SIZE = ROWS * COLUMS;
private int x;
private JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS,COLUMS, GAP,GAP));
private JPanel [] gridPanel = new JPanel[SIZE];
private JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();    
private JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
private Color col1 = Color.GREEN;
private Color col2 = Color.YELLOW;
private Color tempColor;


public Game()
{
    super("Chasing Bombs OFJ2");
    setSize(200,200);
    setVisible(true);
    makeFrame();
}


public void makeFrame()
{
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    leftPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLUMS));

    //JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Pocahontas");

    JButton playButton = new JButton("Play Game");
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");


    JButton easyButton = new JButton("Easy");
    JButton mediumButton = new JButton("Medium");
    JButton hardButton = new JButton("Hard");


    add(leftPanel);

    add(middlePanel, new FlowLayout());

    add(rightPanel);

    setGrid();


    middlePanel.add(playButton);
    middlePanel.add(exitButton);
    rightPanel.add(easyButton);
    rightPanel.add(mediumButton);
    rightPanel.add(hardButton);
    leftPanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    middlePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

    easyButton.addActionListener(this);
    mediumButton.addActionListener(this);
    hardButton.addActionListener(this);
    playButton.addActionListener(this);
    exitButton.addActionListener(this);



}

public void setGrid()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) {
           gridPanel[x] = new JPanel();
           gridPanel[x].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
           leftPanel.add(gridPanel[x]);
           gridPanel[x].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
           gridPanel[x].addActionListener(this);

        }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == gridPanel[0]){
        gridPanel[x].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
}
```

I have tried to find if there is any other method that is needed to do this but cant find anything. Is it possible that I will have to add a button to fill each of the panels to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried doing  'public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener' but get another error saying: Game is not abstract and does not override abstract method MouseExited

Comment: [documentation of JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPanel.html) does not include an `addActionListener` method. What would the action be, what is the event you want to react on? / your comment: could have been added to question - if you want a class to implement an interface (e.g. `MouseListener`) that class must also implement all the method of that interface (e.g. `mouseExited`)

Comment: I need to make the panel react on a mouse click and change colour. What do you mean by needing to impliment all the methods and what are they? thanks @CarlosHeuberger

Comment: if you want to implement an interface you must program all the methods defined in that interface; what they are: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) - but you can also extend from `MauseAdapter` that has all methods implement (empty) and just override the one you need (mouse click) and add that listener (`addMouseListener`) to the panel.Tutorial: [How to Write a Mouse Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

It defaults to no addActionListener, and the code below is a reference suggestion.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class GPanel extends JPanel {
    private List<ActionListener> listenerList = new ArrayList<>();

    public GPanel() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                var event = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "GPanel");
                for (var i : listenerList) {
                    i.actionPerformed(event);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(listener);
    }
}

public class ActionListenerTest extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ActionListenerTest();
    }

    public ActionListenerTest() {
        GPanel test = new GPanel();
        test.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        add(test);
        test.addActionListener(e-> {
            System.out.println("Click: " + e.getActionCommand());
        });
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: So would these be extra classes that would need to be added? Is there not an easier way to change the colour of the JPanel when it is clicked on? Thanks

Comment: Also what is "var"?

Comment: This means you need to implement it in your class.The easier way is to set the mouse listener directly with no extra classes,but it's not conducive to reuse.`var` is a new feature of java10, which means that the type of the variable is automatically determined.